# Adding a new fireplace to upstairs bedroom. Want to tap into existing unused vent

Tags: hvac, fireplace, chimney

Our house used to have a wood burning stove in the basement. We also have a fireplace on the first floor of the house, leaving two separate vents in our chimney.

Before we bought the house it was renovated and a heat pump was added. As such, the basement wood stove was removed. The chimney vent for that stove is obviously still in the chimney so I was wondering if it is possible for a contractor to tap into that vent from our upstairs bedroom. The bedroom is directly adjacent to the chimney (behind drywall) but I figure if we can just tap into that vent it will save some time and money over adding a new stack.

I realize there are probably some building code restrictions in my area, but I am just trying to see if this is something that can be done?

Comment: Are you talking about adding  a wood burning fireplace, or gas?

Comment: Wood preferably, but gas would be a fine alternative

Comment: As you have a heat pump your house is probably well insulated now. The fireplace (gas or wood) needs fresh air to burn so you should also think of an air inlet close to the fireplace. Else the chimney won't have enough draft or cause smoke in the room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will start by saying, if you're willing to spend the time and/or money, almost anything is possible.  My gut feeling is that a wood burning fireplace would generally be out of the question without permits, engineer drawings and significant modifications.

A gas burning fireplace is definitely doable along an exterior wall using direct vent models, bypassing the chimney all together.  Some models can also use the chimney and I would think that as long as your current chimney can provide the necessary clearances of the exhaust vent, it could be used.